# Rails ActiveRecord conditional callback issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby 2.1.8
rails 3.2.18

I am trying to run a callback when a record is saved only if a particular attribute has been changed. For example

```
before_save :do_the_thing, if: :my_attr_changed?
```

However, when I change `my_attr` and save, `do_the_thing` is not getting 
called. And yet, if I do the exact same thing, but with:

```
before_save :do_the_thing

def do_the_thing
  puts my_attr_changed?
end
```

It outputs "true" into the logs. Rather confused here. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use a  a lambda instead of a symbol? `before_save :do_the_thing, if:  ->{ my_attr_changed? }`

Comment: Although using a symbol here should work. Have you created a test which replicates the issue and are completely sure that the error is not in the methodology?

Comment: symbol should work

Comment: @max yes, thanks! I did just try it with lambda and it does work now!

Comment: Thats pretty wierd.

Comment: It is weird... I don't understand but... hey, this works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just move it inside lambda

```
before_save :do_the_thing, if: -> { my_attr_changed? }
```